# Are cycles allowed between platform modules?

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system

This is the module declaration of the `java.rmi` module:

```
module java.rmi {
    requires java.base;
    requires java.logging;

    exports java.rmi.activation;
    exports com.sun.rmi.rmid to java.base; // <-- cycle
    ...
}
```

So, there is a cyclic dependency between `java.rmi` and `java.base`, right? Are cycles allowed between [platform modules](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#platform-modules)?

Comment: @Eugene `com.sun.rmi` is a package that is exported by the module `java.rmi`

Comment: @Eugent `java.rmi` depends on `java.base`. But it also exports its package to `java.base`, so `java.base` apparently needs access to this package (otherwise that line of code didn't make sense).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The module system forbids statically declaring cycles with `requires` clauses. This is true for platform and application modules and the example you give does not violate that rule.

Requires clauses are just one source for readability edges in the module graph, though. Others are command line flags, reflection, `requires transitive`, and I'm sure there are more. Adding all these may result in cycles in the module graph and that is not forbidden.

In your concrete example the cycle is only created once *java.base* reads *java.rmi*, which could happen if it uses reflection on classes in `com.sun.rmi.rmid`.